# CAT.Net 2.0 download

Tags: .net, security, xss, cat.net

Does anyone know where I can find a downloadable copy of CAT.Net 2.0 (beta or not)? I have been lurking a lot, but I can only find broken links to MS Connect site.

Please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if I got this right this is what Microsoft guy says about it last February:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/catnet/thread/31663b6d-254e-48ce-8345-3355cb8b6023

> Hi,   I wanted to provide an update to the CAT.NET project since it’s
>   been a while since my last communication.  Internally we have version
>   2.0 of CAT.NET running.  Unfortunately, some of the features we relied on in Visual Studio’s code analysis did not make it into the final
>   product.  We are working with the Visual Studio team to include the
>   features needed.    In the meantime our team had been investigating
>   options to bypass the missing libraries.  This is not an ideal
>   solution because we’ll be omitting the seamless integration with
>   Visual Studio.   We believe we have a solution and have provided
>   estimates to fix this problem.  Because this effort was not planned,
>   we are investigating how to fit this effort into our current work
>   load.  We should have some news by the end of March if not sooner.
>   Cheers, Frank

notice that the provided download link is broken and you get a page not found from the Microsoft site:

https://connect.microsoft.com/site734/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=26086  :(((

Comment: Also check this out: http://diniscruz.blogspot.co.uk/2012/06/real-time-vulnerability-creation.html